# Calling TargetingIdeaService Crashes randomly

Tags: targeting, google-ads-api

Fellow backend-ers,

I have a curious problem with using TargetingIdeaService. 
I am using the normal template that is provided for php and it works. Problem is that sometimes (maybe 1/10) calls ends in crashing my script. 
I only receive a 500 code in the calling google script and after thoroughly logging I see that it crashes on the line

```
$page = $targetingService->get($selector);
```

So, this is with the same arguments all the time, that sometimes it only ends in a black hole. There's no exception, just silence.
Has anyone experienced something like this?

The service object and the selector are defined like this:

```
// create and setup service
$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
$targetingService = $adWordsServices->get($session, TargetingIdeaService::class);
...
$selector->setIdeaType('KEYWORD');
$selector->setRequestType('STATS');
$selector->setRequestedAttributeTypes(array('KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME'));
```

As for logs I don't have too much to show.
the soap request looks normally like this:

```
[2018-09-26 15:32:35] AW_SOAP.INFO: clientCustomerId=574-260-3578 operations=1 service=TargetingIdeaService method=get responseTime=149 requestId=000576c6414f81880a56e5054f00160b server=adwords.google.com isFault=0 faultMessage=
```

Comment: Could you extend your question with some error logs?

Answer (score 0):

The Adwords API raises server errors all the time. The ones that are relevant for the TargetingIdeaService are [listed here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/TargetingIdeaService#errors).

The log entry you listed is a bit strange in that regard as it seems to be for a successful request—note that the `isFault` attribute is zero and there's no `faultMessage`. Normally you should be able to see what the problem is by investigating that field.

As long as it's not a [persistent error such as an invalid OAuth2 access token](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/bestpractices#distinguish_error_types), the recommended way of dealing with these errors is to retry the request using an exponential backoff strategy.

From personal experience, we get `UNEXPECTED_INTERNAL_API_ERROR` maybe once every couple of thousand operations, and in almost all cases the request succeeds once we re-submit it.

Comment: It might be that the service is quite all right, something on my server is not acting properly. I discovered that actual exceptions that should come from the service end in a crash. Unfortunately I don't have right now the conditions to investigate further. Thanks for the reply.